# Animation stopped working

Tags: leaflet, animation

We have an animation built with leaflet that was working until about a month ago.

Now, the play button is just like an image, and nothing happens when I hover or click on it.
In the inspect element under sources I have the following:

Could not load content for https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/3.12.0/dist/vis.js (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)

May this be the cause and if yes, how I may fix it?

Comment: The error code could not be more clear: 404 means that the file `/ajax/libs/vis/3.12.0/dist/vis.js` does not exist any more on the CDNJS server. How can you fix it: find origin of the library on the GitHub and download the file to where you app runs.

Comment: But since https://github.com/almende/vis is deprecated, one can guess that *maybe* the files from the CDN were pulled off because of the deprecation, and the only way forward is to switch ti `visjs`.